# the buttons in my .kv file just dont function

Tags: python, android, kivy

im new to kivy and creating an android app i was following with a simple tutorial but now none of the buttons in my application work
anyway heres the code in main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (720, 1280)
kivy.require('2.0.0')

darsad=''




def set_darsad(self, value):
    self.darsad.text = str(value)


class MyRoot(GridLayout):

    def clear(self, instance):
        self.masahat.text = ''
        self.result_label.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = ''

    def standard(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '6'
        print(darsad)

    def hosein(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '21'

    def akhavan(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '1584'

    def rasoli(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '13'


    def bizhani(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '27'

    def mohamadi(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '2.5'

    def nikoghadam(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '10'

    def ayazi(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '19'

    def kazemi(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '22'

    def hasanzade(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '135'

    def m_rasoli(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '2.5'

    def karimi(self):
        self.darsad.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = '2.5'



    def calculate(self, instance):
        try:
            a = float(self.masahat.text)
            self.darsad_value = self.darsad
            if self.darsad_value:
                b = float(self.darsad_value)
                c = a * (b / 100)
                x = (a - c) * 2.7  
                rounded_x = round(x, 2)
                self.result_label.text = str(rounded_x)
            else:
                self.result_label.text = 'Enter Darsad Value'
        except ValueError:
            self.result_label.text = 'Invalid Input'





    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()
        self.layout=GridLayout()
        self.layout.cols = 2



class AluminiumMass(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()
        
if __name__ in ('__main__','__android'):
    AluminiumMass().run()
```

and the code in aluminiummass.kv:

```
<MyRoot>:
    cols: 2
    masahat: masahat
    calculate_button: calculate_button
    clear_button: clear_button
    darsad_l: darsad_l
    darsad: darsad
    result_l: result_l
    result_label: result_label
    area: area
    standard: standard
    hosein_momeni: hosein_momeni
    akhavan: akhavan
    rasoli: rasoli
    bijani: bijani
    mohammadi: mohammadi
    nikoghadam: nikoghadam
    ayazi: ayazi
    kazemi: kazemi
    hasanzade: hasanzade
    mojtaba: mojtaba
    alikarimi: alikarimi


    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        orientation: "lr-tb"
        size_hint_y: None 
        height: self.minimum_height

        Label: 
            text: "Area:"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id: area



        TextInput: 
            multiline: False 
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            id: masahat

        Label : 
            text: "Darsad:"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id: darsad_l

        TextInput: 
            multiline: False
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            id: darsad

        Button: 
            text: "Calculate"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id: calculate_button
            on_press: root.calculate

        Button : 
            text: "AC"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id: clear_button
            on_press: root.clear


    




        Label: 
            text: "Answer: "
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            halign: "right"
            valign: "middle"
            bold: True
            id: result_l

        Label: 
            text: ""
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            halign: "left"
            valign: "middle"
            bold: True
            id: result_label
        
        Button:
            text: "Standard"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:standard
            on_press: root.standard

        Button:
            text: "Hosein Momeni"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:hosein_momeni
            on_press: root.hosein

        Button:
            text: "Akhavan"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:akhavan
            on_press: root.akhavan

        Button:
            text: "Rasoli"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:rasoli
            on_press: root.rasoli


        Button:
            text: "Bijani"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:bijani
            on_press: root.bizhani

        Button:
            text: "Mohammadi"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:mohammadi
            on_press: root.mohamadi

        Button:
            text: "Nikoghadam"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:nikoghadam
            on_press: root.nikoghadam

        Button:
            text: "Ayazi"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:ayazi
            on_press: root.ayazi
        Button:
            text: "Kazemi/Darbahani"
            font_size: 24
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:kazemi
            on_press: root.kazemi

        Button:
            text: "Hasanzade"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:hasanzade
            on_press: root.hasanzade

        Button:
            text: "Mojtaba Rasoli"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:mojtaba
            on_press: root.m_rasoli

        Button:
            text: "Ali Karimi"
            font_size: 26
            size_hint: (None, None)  
            size: 200, 60
            bold: True
            id:alikarimi
            on_press: root.karimi
```

im just confused, i tried to define the on_press function of the buttons in the MyRoot() class but it didnt work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Why is ```def set_darsad()``` not within the class?

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyRoot` class, you've defined the various methods but you have not connected them in your KV FILE. Below is the way to modify your `main.py`

```
class MyRoot(GridLayout):

    def clear(self, instance):
        self.masahat.text = ''
        self.result_label.text = ''
        self.darsad.text = ''

    def standard(self, instance):
        self.darsad.text = '6'

    def hosein(self, instance):
        self.darsad.text = '21'

    # ... (similar modifications for other methods)

    def calculate(self, instance):
        # Your existing code for the calculate method

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()
        # Your existing code

        # Bind each button's on_press to its corresponding method
        self.ids.clear_button.bind(on_press=self.clear)
        self.ids.standard.bind(on_press=self.standard)
        self.ids.hosein_momeni.bind(on_press=self.hosein)
        # ... (similar bindings for other buttons)
```

you've already correctly binding for calculate.
Feel free to ask, if you have any doubts.